# How does Codeigniter handle escaping output?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter.

Recently, I read a PHP book and saw some functions to escape output to server to database using

```
*_escape_string()
```

and from server to browser using:

```
htmlentities()
htmlspecialchars()
```

In my Codeigniter application, how are these functions handled?  Is it internally handled by the framework, or do I have to manually handle it?

In Ccodeigniter form validation I have seen `xss_clean`

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|xss_clean|min_length[6]|matches[confirmpassword]' );
```

Is `xss_clean` for preventing cross site scripting, or does it deal with the above I have mentioned?

Comment: One thing to note: You *never* want to use `xss_clean` on a password, like in your example. In fact, you should never alter password input at all, assuming it is hashed before being saved (which it should be, of course).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using the Active Record class, you generally don't need to escape anything you send to your database - it's done automatically:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

> "It also allows for safer queries, since the values are escaped automatically by the system."

Manual escaping seems to be becoming a thing of the past, as most people are using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) now for database interactions, using paramterized queries with placeholders instead of mashing SQL strings together. CI still uses the `mysql_*` functions internally though.

CI's `xss_clean()` is, in my opinion, more of a failsafe for those of us who don't know how and when to escape data properly. You normally don't need it. It's been the target of criticism both for it's slow, aggressive approach to sanitizing data, as well as for just "not being good enough".

For escaping HTML output, in most cases `htmlspecialchars()` is all you need, but you can use the `xss_clean()` function any time. I don't suggest using it as a form validation rule because it will corrupt your input, inserting `[removed]` wherever it found something "naughty" in the original string. Instead, you can just call it manually to clean your **output**.

#### Summary:

- Database: CI will (usually) escape the strings you pass to the Active Record class.
  See the user guide for details: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html
- HTML **output**: You need to escape HTML output yourself with `htmlspecialchars()` or use CI's `html_escape()` function (as of 2.1.0). This is *not* done automatically because there's no way to know the context in which you are using the data.
- `xss_clean()` - If you know what you're doing, you shouldn't need it. Better to use on output than input.

Comment: What is the difference between CI's html_escape() and php's htmlspecialchars() ?

Comment: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/938c7e4e4d874189fec2bec8532ed70bb8c52f05/system/core/Common.php#L737

Comment: xss_clean() should be only used upon form submission because it is very slow.

Answer (score 2):

Default CodeIgniter views are just PHP, so you can use htmlentities() and htmlspecialchars() in your view files.

For escaping data into the database (i.e. preventing SQL injection) CodeIgniter offers parameterised queries.  Basically, put a ? in the SQl wherever you want to insert a peice of data, then supply all of the data in an array.  See "Query Bindings" at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html.  Also on that page see "Escaping Queries" which describes the CI wrappers for the *_escape_string functions.  However, query bindings/parameterised queries are a better approach.

Comment: so then  htmlentities() and htmlspecialchars() are not  handled internally by the framework ??

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya No, because _escaping_ or whatever you can call it should happen just before using that value. If CI would encode _any_ html _per se_, no matter what, nothing would work on your view. HTML needs escaping right before being output on the page, and only if you want it. So no sane framework out there would sanitizie html as soon as it's seen by the code. Hope I'm clear

Answer (score 0):

In codeignater if you are not using active record class  then just in sql query use

```
$this->db->escape($varaiable)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add This Function in custom helper file

```
function escape_output($string)
{
    $newString = str_replace('\r\n','<br/>',$string);
    $newString = str_replace('\n\r','<br/>',$newString);
    $newString = str_replace('\r','<br/>',$newString);
    $newString = str_replace('\n','<br/>',$newString);
    $newString = str_replace('\'','',$newString);
    return $newString;
}
```

> Call function in view

```
<?php echo escape_output("Bhavin\'s \"code"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function:

```
function my_escape($str) {
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $str = stripslashes($str);
}
return str_replace("'", "''", $str);
}
```