# codenigiter: sql injection and xss_clean

Tags: codeigniter, xss, sql-injection

I am using active record in codenigiter to do some query and I read some docs that say using AR will escape the parameter automaticly.I want to comfirm this and I read the source code of AR class,but I am confused!
I do some test,eg,I access the url as follow is:

```
http://wrecruit.tudouya.com/company/editProfile/4
```

then I enable the profiler in CI.

when I add a single quote at the end of url as follows:

```
http://wrecruit.tudouya.com/company/editProfile/4'
```

I see the real sql statement the query execute and I got this:

```
 SELECT *
FROM (`wy_company`)
WHERE `id` =  '4%27'
```

**the single quote is escaped to '%27',I want to know how this escape happen?maybe it's escaped by the input class?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Codeigniter handle escaping output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722099/how-does-codeigniter-handle-escaping-output)

Comment: I want to know how the single quote is escpaed to %27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Url adress is always encoded with urlencode function. This function replace all symbols with codes.
If you want to prevent xss you should to check you parameter. May be like this (in controller Company):

```
public function editProfile($id)
{
    $id = (int)$id;

    if($id){
        // model code execute - loading DB data
    }
}
```

And in DB query you should use [Query Bindings](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html), or use Active record. Them both are prevent injection.

Comment: thank you friend!you say "Url adress is always encoded with urlencode function",this is what I want to know and I also want to know where the urlencode function is applied?